# JSON MVC changes the Content Type

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have my basic controller and want to return JSON data as a string. It will NOT be used in AJAX.

In my view I have this:

```
<script>
    var myJson = @Html.Action("JsonMethod","Controller")
    // Some JS that need JSON data...
</script>
```

And my controller looks like this

```
public ActionResult JsonMethod() {
    return Content(Json("Test").ToString());
}
```

It seems like that I only need to touch the Json object and it will go to `HttpContext.Current.Response` and change the content type so `application/json` which will make the view unusable. Am I right about that the Json object requiere a HttpContext, and will by using it, change the content type

Comment: you do not want the response in JSON format ?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a model for this?  you mention that this is not ajax so you must be doing this server side in the view.

Comment: You could use the javascriptserializer to get the json as a string and stick it in the viewbag/viewdata or a model

Comment: @RichAndrews Yes, I'm using the Javascript Serializer now insteed. But I just thought it would be handy to use the Json object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Json("Test")
```

The above is actually a method on the controller, when called it does more than convert the object to JSON, like change the content-type as you found.

You probably want to use the JavaScriptSerializer directly and place the serialized string in your ViewBag or model.

You can also just create an extension method to accomplish this directly in the view.

```
public static class Helpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString GetJson(this HtmlHelper helper, object obj)
    {
        return new MvcHtmlString(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj));
    }
}
```

And then in the view.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myJson = @Html.GetJson(new {test="Test Value"});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's the Content method on the controller that is interpreting the content type based on the json string.

Try using the contentype overload http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492713(v=vs.98).aspx to tell it you want text/plain.

Answer (score 0):

Try this please:

```
return Content(Json("Test").Data.ToString());
```

Your javascript code will be like that:

```
var myJson = Test
```